How to configure unbound with --enable-dnstap: Issue protoc-c... no
When configuring unbound with --enable-dnstap, it can't locate protobuf-c.
$ ./configure --enable-dnstap
...
...
...
checking for protoc-c... no
configure: error: The protoc-c program was not found. Please install protobuf-c!

However, protobuf-c appears to be installed.
$ sudo apt search protobuf-c
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libprotobuf-c-dev/stable,now 1.4.1-1+b1 armhf [installed]
  Protocol Buffers C static library and headers (protobuf-c)

libprotobuf-c1/stable,now 1.4.1-1+b1 armhf [installed,automatic]
  Protocol Buffers C shared library (protobuf-c)

librust-prometheus+protobuf-codegen-pure-dev/stable 0.13.3-1 armhf
  Prometheus instrumentation library for Rust applications - feature "protobuf-codegen-pure" and 1 more

librust-protobuf-codegen-dev/stable 2.27.1-1+b2 armhf
  Code generator for rust-protobuf - Rust source code

librust-protobuf-codegen-pure-dev/stable 2.27.1-1 armhf
  Pure-rust codegen for protobuf using protobuf-parser crate - Rust source code

protobuf-c-compiler/stable 1.4.1-1+b1 armhf
  Protocol Buffers C compiler (protobuf-c)

protobuf-codegen/stable 2.27.1-1+b2 armhf
  Code generator for rust-protobuf

protobuf-compiler/stable 3.21.12-3 armhf
  compiler for protocol buffer definition files

protobuf-compiler-grpc/stable 1.51.1-3+b1 armhf
  high performance general RPC framework - protobuf plugin

protobuf-compiler-grpc-java-plugin/stable 1.41.3+ds-1 armhf
  high performance general RPC framework - protobuf Java plugin  
$ dpkg -l | grep protobuf
ii  libprotobuf-c-dev:armhf              1.4.1-1+b1                              armhf        Protocol Buffers C static library and headers (protobuf-c)
ii  libprotobuf-c1:armhf                 1.4.1-1+b1                              armhf        Protocol Buffers C shared library (protobuf-c)
$ sudo find / -name libprotobuf-c1
/usr/share/doc/libprotobuf-c1
$ sudo find / -name libprotobuf-c-dev
/usr/share/doc/libprotobuf-c-dev
$ ls /usr/bin/ | grep proto
$ ls /usr/local/bin/ | grep proto
$ ls /bin/ | grep proto
$ ls /usr/lib/ | grep proto
$ ls /usr/local/lib/ | grep proto
$ ls /lib/ | grep proto
$

I can't locate the protobuf-c library or program either although it is installed.
I do I resolve this configuration issue?
Update:
I discovered from this answer that the library name is libprotobuf-c.so.1.
Its location was found using:
$ sudo find / -name libprotobuf-c.so.1
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libprotobuf-c.so.1
$

I tried linking this file into /usr/local/lib (Unbound default installation library directory) via
$ ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libprotobuf-c.so.1 

and reran
$ ./configure --enable-dnstap

and still got the same error msg as mentioned above.
I further tried:
./configure --enable-dnstap --with-protobuf-c=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libprotobuf-c.so.1

and still got the same error msg as mentioned above.
The unbound version that I am trying to configure is 1.22.0.
This question does not duplicate How do I find the package that provides a file?. Reasons:

I am already using dpkg.
I found that using apt search to be more suitable as it shows all the other packages related to protobuf-c with description.
Apart from the libprotobuf-c, unbound also uses the protoc-c program (informed to me by an unbound member), which is available after installing protobuf-c-compiler (see @steeldriver comment). This information isn't disclosed using dpkg.


The "protoc-c program", /usr/bin/protoc-c, appears to be provided by package protobuf-c-compiler

This question is similar to: How do I find the package that provides a file?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@muru I have added an explanation.

As can be clearly seen from the other answers to that post, you need to use other tools for finding packages of files which are not already installed.

To configure unbound with the option --enable-dnstap, these apt packages need to be installed first:
$ sudo apt install libprotobuf-c1 libprotobuf-c-dev protobuf-c-compiler

